# Best approach to mock this NodeJS Kubernetes client for a unit test in Jest?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

Am trying to use this NodeJS Kubernetes client:
https://github.com/godaddy/kubernetes-client#examples

Am struggling a little to mock my calls using this client in a unit test. Given the examples linked above what is the best way to mock the get() call here on the LAST line?

```
// Using a little wrapper to return my custom instantiated kubernetes-client
const getClient = require('./utils/getClient')

// lets assume we're in an async function
const myClient = await getClient()
const deploymentConfigs = await myClient.apis.apps.v1.namespaces('mynamespace').deployments.get()
```

I have tried this approach in my test with no success :

```
const getClient = require('../utils/getClient')
jest.mock('../utils.getClient')

const mockGet = jest.fn()

getClient.mockImplementation(() => {
  return {
    apis: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    apps: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    v1: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    namespaces: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    buildconfigs: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    get: mockGet
  }
})
```

Using this `getClient.mockImplementation` I keep receiving the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'v1')
```

when this line is called:

```
const deploymentConfigs = await myClient.apis.apps.v1.namespaces('mynamespace').deployments.get()
```

Comment: Jest's [mockReturnThis()](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockreturnthis) returns the `jest.fn()`, not the outer object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try mocking it like this:

```
const namespaces = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
  deployments: {
    get: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(mockDeployments),
  },
});

getClient.mockResolvedValue({
  apis: {
    apps: {
      v1: {
        namespaces,
      },
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: Very nice! I actually tried something very similar after posting, and got it working too but yours is a little more elegant and clean. I like it! Thanks @Teneff !

Comment: Sorry to necro this but: How would you mock out both styles of `namespaces`, i.e. `client.api.v1.namespaces(namespace).get()` vs `client.api.v1.namespaces.post(someJson)`?

Comment: @Resisty I don't see what's the exact problem that you're facing, you can post a new question and link it here in the comment

Comment: @Teneff sure: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74630232/how-do-you-mock-a-callable-object-in-jest