# How do you mock a callable object in jest?

Tags: node.js, jestjs, mocking

Specific example from kubernetes-client:

Application code:

```
  console.log(`Trying to create a namespace: ${namespaceName}`)
  try {
    await client.api.v1.namespaces(namespaceName).get()
  } catch (err) {
    try {
      await client.api.v1.namespaces.post(namespaceJson)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Error creating namespace: ' + err)
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        reject(new Error(`Failure creating namespace: ${namespaceName}: ${err}`))
      })
    }
...
```

Tests:

```
    jest.doMock('kubernetes-client', () => {
      const aRejection = jest.fn(() => {
        const err = new Error(404)
        err.response = 'Not found'
        err.status = 404
        err.statusCode = 404
        return Promise.reject(err)
      })
      const aPromise = jest.fn(() => {
        return Promise.resolve({
          body: {
            data: {
              username: 'dXNlcm5hbWUK' // 'username', base64-encoded
            }
          }
        })
      })
      const namespaces = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
        get: aRejection,
        post: aPromise
      })
      const mockClient = {
        api: {
          v1: {
            namespaces
          }
        },
      }
      return {
        Client: jest.fn(() => mockClient),
      }
    })
```

Note that `client.api.v1.namespaces.post(namespaceJson)` (namespaces is an object) and `client.api.v1.namespaces(namespace).get()` (namespaces is a function) are both valid.

If I mock namespaces as a function, the tests fail because `client.api.v1.namespaces.post()` is not a function.

Hopefully I'm just doing something wrong somewhere but I don't know what that is.